# How to fix NodeJS Firebase AdminSDK GoogleError?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

NodeJS Firebase AdminSDK GoogleError: Total timeout of API google.firestore.v1.Firestore exceeded 600000 milliseconds before any response was received

I am running a Node script to commit batches to the firestore. After 5-10 minutes of running the script **locally**, this error is returned:

```
GoogleError: Total timeout of API google.firestore.v1.Firestore exceeded 600000 milliseconds before any response was received.
    at repeat (E:\Personal\NodeJs\Scraper\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\normalCalls\retries.js:66:31)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Personal\NodeJs\Scraper\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\normalCalls\retries.js:101:25)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
Caused by: Error
    at WriteBatch.commit (E:\Personal\NodeJs\Scraper\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\write-batch.js:417:23)
    at upload (E:\Personal\NodeJs\Scraper\lib\index.js:127:23) {
  code: 4
}
```

It is returned randomly whilst running the script so it is not an issue from the code.

Comment: I suggest you provide the Node JS script, as it might be helpful in finding the root cause.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Nutritioustim no I didn't, after this error I stopped working on the project and moved on to others :(